# Php documentation for /* */

Tags: php

Wherever I go I see documentation for php with the following:

```
/*
* stuff 
* stuff 2
*/
```

My question is can I get away with just:

```
/* 
Stuff 1 
Stuff 2
*/
```

Or is that for some reason counter indicated thanks?

Comment: I mean if the comment works in the 2nd way mentioned then yes you can do that all you want. I don't see why anyone would do the first way if you can do it the second way.

Comment: See the manual http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.comments.php and its notes in particular.

Comment: I have inserted the formatting for you.  Just awaiting for it to be peer reviewed.

Comment: Thanks for the formatting

Comment: thx for the comment user8698551

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually when you see coding habits following a particular pattern it is down to one of the following reasons:

1. Syntax denotes it
2. Coding style requests it
3. Programmatic parsing is enhanced by it.

With comments it is generally the latter two.

There are a number of coding styles for the `/**/` comment block, across numerous languages (not just PHP). Coding styles generally are just personal/team preference, usually with some real arguments as to why a particular habit is preferred. Most often, readability is king.

The most common of these particular comment-styles would be what is referred to as a DocComment or DocBlock.

http://docs.phpdoc.org/guides/docblocks.html

This is a way of programatically powering the generation of your documentation directly from comments. Because the comments are parsed by code, it is specified with a particular pattern (note the `/**` prefix), making things easier to detect and reformat:

```
/**
 * This is my DocBlock
 *
 * Each new line is prefix with a *
 * and any special attributes are
 * prefixed with an @something
 */
```

You by no means have to do this though, and a simple `/*` and `*/` will suffice for multiline comments. On the projects that I have worked on in the past, the difference between using a `*` on every line and not makes it clear when a comment is a real comment, against when it is just being used to comment out a portion of code.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, yes you can!

When creating `.php` files, the developer will often insert comments, as to add explanations for their coding.

There are two ways of adding comments.  They are as follows:

- `/*[Comment Here]*/` This allows the Developer to add comments, which spread over multiple lines.  For example:

  `/*
  [This is a Comment]
  [This is also a Comment]
  */`

You just need to ensure that your Comment falls within the `/**/` and that these are enclosed within the `<?php [Code Data] ?>` tags.

- Alternatively, you can use `'//'`.  Unlike the above, this will only allow you to insert a Comment on one line.  If you were to go into the next line, you would need to add an additional `//`.  Just like the above, you need to also ensure these `//` are placed within the `<php? [Code Data] >` tags.

As for the list of '*', I believe this is just for presentational and organisational purposes.  They certainly do not affect the Comment itself.

Comment: Thanks you have been helpful as well

Comment: My apologies.  @patrick is right here.  I am thinking of the HTML Methods of commenting ... `<!--[Comments]-->`  which are publically visible in the Source Code.  I will ammend my answer accordingly.

Comment: @johndoe No worries.  Glad you got your answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The format you're describing is called PHPDoc.  It's often used to document classes and methods (IDEs can make use of PHPDoc).  This comment format is sometimes required to store annotations for various frameworks and libraries (e.g. Symfony uses it on controllers for routing.)

If you're not using annotations or documenting classes/functions, then there's no reason to write in the PHPDoc convention.

PHPDoc:

http://www.phptherightway.com/#phpdoc

Symfony annotation example (see the @Route examples):

https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html